# Как автоматизировать update таблицы mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Приходят данные через пост, их может быть как 10 так и 15, а может и вовсе 1, зависит от настроек пользователя.

Нужно данными которое пришли обновить таблицу.

И делать

```php
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
  $usr_upd = $dbpdo->prepare(" UPDATE user SET user_name = :user_name ");
  $usr_upd->bindParam('user_name', $_POST['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $usr_upd->execute();
}

if(isset($_POST['sname'])) {
   //code
}

//etc
```

Делать проверки ифами 20 раз, мне кажется не лучший вариант, если не худший.
Думаю с подобной задачей(проблемой) уже кто-то сталкивался и наверняка есть оптимальное решение.
Знающих прошу помочь, буду благодарен.

Comment: а какой код должен быть если `sname` существует? Он отличается от предыдущего? А какие примерно ещё переменные ожидаются и какие операции под них ожидаются? одинаковые или все разные?

Comment: 1) Показанный запрос обновляет всю таблицу, заменяя `user_name` всех записей на заданное... что как бы странненько. Где условия отбора-то?  2) Какая **точно** версия MySQL? 3) Есть возможность в PHP весь переданный массив единым махом преобразовать в CSV-строку (типа `'name,Vasily,sname,Pupkin,...'`) или JSON-объект (типа `{"name":"Vasily","sname":"Pupkin",...}'`)? 4) *их может быть как 10 так и 15, а может и вовсе 1* А максимально - сколько?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , есть операторы и расчеты в самом запросе, например ``` col_name = col_name + :count ```

Comment: @Akina . 
1) это для примера я написал и забыл "условие отбора"
2) phpMyAdmin показывает - 5.02
3) да
4) максимум 20

Comment: *phpMyadmin показывает - 5.02* Ниачём. `SELECT VERSION();` что выводит? полностью...

Comment: @Akina 10.4.13-MariaDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример.

Таблица и данные:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE user (id INT PRIMARY KEY,
>                    fname VARCHAR(64),
>                    lname VARCHAR(64),
>                    age INT);
> INSERT INTO user VALUES
> (1, 'Vassily', 'Pupkin', 20),
> (2, 'idiosinkrazy', 'Ziper-Molnienossny', 25);
> SELECT * FROM user;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | fname        | lname              | age
> -: | :----------- | :----------------- | --:
>  1 | Vassily      | Pupkin             |  20
>  2 | idiosinkrazy | Ziper-Molnienossny |  25
> ```

Переданные параметры для обновления:

> ```
> SET @parameters := '{"id":1,"fname":"Vasily","age":21}';
> ```

Запрос на обновление и результат:

> ```
> UPDATE user
> SET fname = COALESCE(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(@parameters, "$.fname")), fname),
>     lname = COALESCE(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(@parameters, "$.lname")), lname),
>     age = COALESCE(JSON_EXTRACT(@parameters, "$.age"), age)
> WHERE id = JSON_EXTRACT(@parameters, "$.id");
> SELECT * FROM user;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | fname        | lname              | age
> -: | :----------- | :----------------- | --:
>  1 | Vasily       | Pupkin             |  21
>  2 | idiosinkrazy | Ziper-Molnienossny |  25
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=40886aa8e9d96c744c0ffe129e8a73c3)*

PS. Строковые данные в JSON (не в таблице!) требуют JSON_UNQUOTE, числовые нет.

Comment: В английском есть хорошее слово, overengineering.

Comment: @Ипатьев да нормально.. засунет в хранимую процедуру и забудет... до изменения структуры данных и/или таблицы.

Comment: Да какие там процедуры. Это для него звучит как брахмавайвартапурана. Тут же видно что человек две недели в пхп, простой цикл с парой условий написать не может. и база у него называется пхпмайадмин. какие там процедуры

Comment: @Ипатьев Фигня, научится... для нас оно когда-то тоже было как ангидрид-его-терпингидратом..